# Occurence of a value in many lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, series

i have a Series Object in pandas with 2 columns, one for the indices and one with lists,
I need to find if a value occurs in only one of these lists and return it with the most optimal way.

As an example let's say we have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKdw3.png)

i need to return 77 because it occurs in only one of these lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode` then `value_counts`:

```
df['list_col'].explode().value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==1]
```